# Get distance and duration to closest matrix in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have an logic to find the most optimised to perform delivery.
Lets say, I have location A,B,C. So need distance and duration from A to B, B to A, A to C, C to A, B to C and C to B.

I know how to come out with above query. Example result would be NewMatrix in fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cce7/1

I have a table where I store current matrix we have based on past deliveries. (AppMatrix in table above)

So I need to lookup distance and duration in this table, to find closest matching origin and destination. I have created following function which works just perfect to get my answer :

```
SELECT TOP 1 Distance, ([Time]/60) as Duration FROM [AppMatrix]
ORDER BY ABS([OriginSiteLat] - @OriginLat) + ABS([OriginSiteLng] - @OriginLong)
,ABS([DestSiteLat] - @DestinationLat) + ABS([DestSiteLng] - @DestinationLong)
```

The problem is slowness. Since I need to perform these call with each matrix (I can have 700 different deliveries in a day, 700*700 = 14000, this just too slow  - it takes few hours to return result)

I'm working on best how to limit the data, but any advise on how to optimize performance is appreciated. Maybe advice on how to use spatial here would help.

This is my current code :

```
SELECT * FROM CT as A
INNER JOIN CT AS B ON A.Latitude <> B.Latitude AND A.Longitude<>B.Longitude
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[ufn_ClosestLocation](A.Latitude,A.Longitude, B.Latitude, B.Longitude) R
```

Comment: Are you aware that the delta between the latitude and longitude is not necessary the actual distance between two points (q.v. the Haversine formula) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes understand. The distance I have in AppMatrix table are the actual distance . We have another instance that runs to get actual distance and time and populated that table. But in case that is not found, we just want to find the closest match.